# Array dinamico en C

Tags: c, array

Tengo este pequeño código de un ejercicio de array dinámico, me introduce hasta 6 elementos y me los visualiza correctamente, pero si le pongo a partir de 8, salta un error "el programa dejo de funcionar"

Código:

```
int main()
{
    int cantidad;
    int *x;

    printf("Cantidad de valores del array: ");
    scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("Numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }

    //Visualizar Datos
    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d",x[i]);
    }
    
    free(x);        

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que no estás reservando espacio para el almacenamiento de la información. Prueba con:

```
x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cantidad);
```

Un saludo,

Comment: Oh vaya, que error el mío, gracias amigo :)

Comment: recuerda liberar memoria, con `free` de lo contrario será un memory leak